# How to access other model fields from new View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to build a Wish list, I have a model for the listings, and a model for the wish list,
I have succeeded in making it work but..

I have to loop over all the listings first and match with the product id in my wish list so i can access the fields such as title and image..

is there any easier way to do this than looping over all the listings until finding the matched ones ?

views.py

```
def add_to_wishlist(request, product_id):
    product = WishList.objects.filter(listing_id=product_id, user=request.user.username)
    if product:
        product.delete()
    else:
        product = WishList()
        product.listing_id = product_id
        product.user = request.user.username
        product.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])


def wishlist(request):
    product = WishList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    all_listings = AuctionListing.objects.all()
    return render(request, "auctions/wishlist.html", {
        'wishlist': product,
        'all_listings': all_listings
    })
```

models.py

```
class AuctionListing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_bid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Default_Value")


class WishList(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    listing_id = models.IntegerField()
```

wishlist.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Users Wishlist {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="col-12 mx-auto">
    <h1 class="h3">My Wishlist</h1>
    <div>Manage your wishlist</div>
    {% if wishlist %}
         {% for listing in all_listings %}
            {% for product in wishlist %}
                {% if listing.id == product.listing_id%}
                    <div class="card-mb-3">
                        <div class="row g-0">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img src="{{ listing.image }}" class="img-responsive" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{listing.title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text"> {{listing.description}}</p>
                                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{listing.start_bid}}</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
        <p class="card-text">No products have been added to your wishlist yet</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well, can you just do a search by listing_id and/or by something like title that you would filter with your models?

Comment: Ideally you could do with some relationships between the two things. Probably a `ManyToMany` so that products/listings can exist on people's wish lists. That'd make it much easier to then show the data in question. Because at the moment it looks like a `WishList` can store a number which is hopefully the ID of an `AuctionListing` object, but you've got to maintain that link and do all the sanity checking around it. That also means that a wish list can only contain 1 item.

Comment: I have filtered by the listing_id but how can I access the AuctionListings model fields using my wishlist listing_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're getting all the `WishList` objects for the user, you don't need to just gather all `AuctionListing` objects and iterate over them. You can query them using the IDs on the `WishLists` you get back.

I'd do something like;

`views.py`

```
def wishlist(request):
    wishlists = WishList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    listing_ids = wishlists.values_list('listing_id', flat=True)
    listings = AuctionListing.objects.filter(pk__in=listing_ids)
    
    return render(request, "auctions/wishlist.html", {
        'wishlists': wishlists,
        'listings': listings
    })
```

`wishlist.html`

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Users Wishlist {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="col-12 mx-auto">
    <h1 class="h3">My Wishlist</h1>
    <div>Manage your wishlist</div>
    {% if wishlists and listings %}

          {% for listing in listings %}
                    <div class="card-mb-3">
                        <div class="row g-0">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <img src="{{ listing.image }}" class="img-responsive" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{listing.title}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text"> {{listing.description}}</p>
                                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{listing.start_bid}}</small></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p class="card-text">No products have been added to your wishlist yet</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: ah..I See..This worked, I've added objects in the value_list 
listing_ids = WishList.objects.values_list('listing_id', flat=True)
Thank you very much!